# Webpack sources concatenation in existing angular project

Tags: angularjs, webpack, concatenation

I have an existing **angular** project that uses **grunt** for building tasks. I'm planning to migrate to **webpack**. According to webpack documentation I must use **CommonJS** style in all my script files that I would like to have in a result bundle, because it is the way whick webpack uses for dependency resolving.

But Angular.js already has its own dependency resolving feature that allows not to define explicitly all dependencies in CommonJS style. So I would like to use simple concatenation for my JS files instead of adding `require(...)` to each file of the large project. In my opinion, it would be extra unnecessary work, because there is no difference in file order when you're using angular.

But it looks like webpack pushes me to use CommonJS approach and make a lot of changes in existing codebase without any profit for the project. As I know, I can't use a regular expression or "star"-syntax in `entry` configuration parameter, like this:

```
{
    entry: './scripts/**/*.js',
    //...
}
```

so I must either use CommonJS approach or gerenate a huge array with all application filenames: https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#entry. But this approach looks like a workaround.

Is there a way to make a required simple concatenation of source files using webpack?

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this, because that is just not what webpack is made for. Webpack is not a minifier, but really is a module bundler. It bundles modules. If your code is not organized as modules, webpack won't really be of any use to you.

If you don't use a module system you will not gain anything by using webpack over your current grunt setup.